# Beam: how to unique data by date

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to get users login days from given data

```
  uid     ts
  u1     2019-08-01
  u2     2019-08-01
  u2     2019-08-01
  u1     2019-08-01
  u1     2019-08-02
  u3     2019-08-02
  u1     2019-08-03
  u3     2019-08-03
  u3     2019-08-03
```

And the results

```
uid  day number
u1    3
u2    1
u3    2
```

My current solution, unqiue `ts` after one hour `window`, then store the result to `redis` `set` with `uid` as key and `ts` as value.

```py
class UniqueFn(beam.CombineFn):
    def create_accumulator(self):
        return set()

    def add_input(self, mutable_accumulator, element):
        if element not in mutable_accumulator:
            mutable_accumulator.add(element)
        return mutable_accumulator

    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
        return set.union(*accumulators)

    def extract_output(self, accumulator):
        return list(accumulator)

...

        window_events = (
            filtered_events
            | "UseFixedWindow" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(60 * 60))
        )

        (
            window_events
            | 'Group Date By User ID' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem['uid'], elem['ts']))
            | 'Compute Unique User Date' >> beam.CombinePerKey(UniqueFn())
        )
```

I plan to enlarge the window to one day (24 * 60 * 60), however, there are  lots of data one day. And I am not sure `google data flow` could handle it well.

Is there any better solution to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow should be able to process large amount of data. However, their are certain limitations which can be mitigated by restructuring the pipeline. This can only be known once you have a rough estimate about the shape of the data.

To begin with, I think using following code should be easy and concise.

```
class ExtractWindow(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
    val, count = element
    yield (val, count, window.start)


window_events = (
        filtered_events
        | "UseFixedWindow" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(24* 60 * 60))
    )



(
        window_events
        | 'Group Date By User ID' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: elem['uid'])
        | 'Compute Unique User Date' >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement()
        | 'Extract Window' >> beam.ParDo(ExtractWindow())
    )
```